# How do i use pkg-config with visual studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, protocol-buffers, pkg-config

I am trying to use protobuf on windows (cpp) and the only way to make it work is to link all dependencies (entire /lib folder).

On linux this is somehow done with pkg config. On windows i have to go to linker->input and manually write tens of libraries by hand. How can i use pkg config for that?